# Vertical align messed up by border

Tags: html, css

As shown in the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xzeo4kgf/4/) with the following HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div class="main_container">
      <div class="question">
        <p>Test question here</p>
      </div>  
      <input class="answer" type="text">
      <input class="submit" type="submit">
    </div>
  </body>
```

And CSS:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';

body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  //background-color: rgba(0,150,250,0.75);
}

.question {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0,150,250,0.75);
  border-width: 2em;

  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 10em;
}

.question>p {
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
}

.answer {
  font-size: 1.618em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

I am able to get the test question centered if I remove the `border-style:solid` property of question. However, I am wondering why with border-style it is not centered. I've tried using `box-sizing:border-box` to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Vertical align is messed up because browser applied top bottom margin in p tag, if you removed it this will solve your problem

```
.question > p {
   margin: 0;
}
```

or

```
p {
   margin: 0;
}
```

see my updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xzeo4kgf/8/)

Answer (score 1):

There is by default margin on `p` elements, so when there is no border on parent element what happens is [`margin collapsing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) on `parent-child` and that margin doesn't affect position of `p`. But when you set border (it can be any border as you can see here [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xzeo4kgf/6/)) on parent element you prevent margin-collapsing and now you can see margin on `p` element.

So one solution is to remove margin from `p`

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';
 body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  //background-color: rgba(0,150,250,0.75);

}
.question {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(0, 150, 250, 0.75);
  border-width: 2em;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 10em;
}
.question>p {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.answer {
  font-size: 1.618em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="question">
    <p>Test question here</p>
  </div>
  <input class="answer" type="text">
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having the parent `div` displayed as a `table` and the `p` displayed as a `table-cell` then use `vertical-align`.

See the below snippet.

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';

body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  //background-color: rgba(0,150,250,0.75);
}

.question {
  border: 2em solid rgba(0,150,250,.75);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 10em;
  display: table;
}

.question p {
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.answer {
  font-size: 1.618em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1.618em;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="main_container">
      <div class="question">
        <p>Test question here</p>
      </div>  
      <input class="answer" type="text">
      <input class="submit" type="submit">
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update inner paragraph positions to absolute and remove the margins

and update outer div of paragraph position to relative

see working fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xzeo4kgf/5/)

```
.question {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,150,250,0.75);
    border-width: 2em;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1.618em;
    margin: 5em auto;
    width: 75%;
    height: 10em;
    position: relative;
}

.question>p {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 1.618em;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set margin 0px of p tag. Sample is

```
.question>p {
 background-color:red;
 border-radius: 1.618em;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%); 
 margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox here:

1.) Add `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` to `.question`

2.) Add `margin: auto 0;` to `.question > p`.

3.) Erase everything else except border-radius from `.question > p`

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35jhjqcx/